# Python buffer copy speed - why is array slower than string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, performance, stdvector

I have a buffer object in C++ that inherits from `std::vector<char>`. I want to convert this buffer into a Python string so that I can send it out over the network via Twisted's protocol.transport.write.

Two ways I thought of doing this are (1) making a string and filling it char by char:

```
def scpychar(buf, n):
    s = ''
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        s += buf[i]
    return s
```

and (2) making a char array (since I know how big the buffer is), filling it and converting it to a string

```
def scpyarr(buf, n):
    a = array.array('c','0'*n)
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        a[i] = buf[i]
    return a.tostring()
```

I would have thought that (1) has to make a new string object every time `s += buf[i]` is called, and copy the contents of the old string. So I was expecting (2) to be quicker than (1). But if I test this using timeit, I find that (1) is actually about twice as fast as (2).

I was wondering if someone could explain why (1) is faster?

Bonus points for an even more efficient way to convert from a `std::vector<char>` to a Python string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython can sometimes optimize string `+=` to be in-place if it can determine that no one is keeping a reference to the old string. Algorithm (1) probably triggered the optimization, so it didn't suffer the quadratic runtime it otherwise would have. However, this behavior is not guaranteed, and other Python implementations may not support it.

Try

```
''.join(buf)
```

It should offer linear-time performance on any Python implementation, unlike (1), and faster than (2).

Comment: I didn't think join would accept the vector, but it does. Cool!

Comment: interesting, do you have a reference about cpython in-place modifications?

Comment: @RyanHaining: See note 6 [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Answer (score 0):

import dis and look at dis.dis(scpyarr) and dis.dis(scpychar).
scpychar has less number of interpreter operations.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def scpyarr(buf, n):
...     a = array.array('c','0'*n)
...     for i in xrange(0, n):
...         a[i] = buf[i]
...     return a.tostring()
... 
>>> dis.dis(scpyarr)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (array)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (array)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('c')
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('0')
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (n)
             15 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             19 STORE_FAST               2 (a)

  3          22 SETUP_LOOP              37 (to 62)
             25 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (xrange)
             28 LOAD_CONST               3 (0)
             31 LOAD_FAST                1 (n)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             37 GET_ITER            
        >>   38 FOR_ITER                20 (to 61)
             41 STORE_FAST               3 (i)

  4          44 LOAD_FAST                0 (buf)
             47 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             50 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             51 LOAD_FAST                2 (a)
             54 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             57 STORE_SUBSCR        
             58 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           38
        >>   61 POP_BLOCK           

  5     >>   62 LOAD_FAST                2 (a)
             65 LOAD_ATTR                2 (tostring)
             68 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             71 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def scpychar(buf, n):
...     s = ''
...     for i in xrange(0, n):
...         s += buf[i]
...     return s
... 
>>> dis.dis(scpychar)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
              3 STORE_FAST               2 (s)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              37 (to 46)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (n)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             21 GET_ITER            
        >>   22 FOR_ITER                20 (to 45)
             25 STORE_FAST               3 (i)

  4          28 LOAD_FAST                2 (s)
             31 LOAD_FAST                0 (buf)
             34 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             37 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             38 INPLACE_ADD         
             39 STORE_FAST               2 (s)
             42 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
        >>   45 POP_BLOCK           

  5     >>   46 LOAD_FAST                2 (s)
             49 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

Compare it:

```
         51 LOAD_FAST                2 (a)
         54 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
         57 STORE_SUBSCR
```

plus

```
  >>   62 LOAD_FAST                2 (a)
         65 LOAD_ATTR                2 (tostring)
         68 CALL_FUNCTION            0
```

vs

```
         38 INPLACE_ADD         
         39 STORE_FAST
```

Load is slow. CALL_FUNCTION is slow.

I seen in question, month ago, that `''.join(b)` was fastest way to join array of chars into one string.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can see why it happened.  Number of instructions is a priori only weakly correlated with performance.

Comment: Its not really the number of instructions but rather the memory consumption and CPU time.

Comment: @SeanMcLaughlin but i see number of __heavy__ instructions in scpyarr is more.

Comment: This answer says nothing to address the expected quadratic runtime of algorithm (1).

Comment: @user2357112 twice more heavy instructions - twice more time. Whats wrong?

Comment: Instructions don't take a constant amount of time. If the in-place concatenation optimization didn't kick in, that `INPLACE_ADD` would take more and more time each time.

Comment: Also, the number of instructions means very little. An unrolled loop could have 8 times as many instructions as the unoptimized form and still run faster.

Comment: @user2357112 in one code optimizations may happen very often, in another code sample it happens __newer__ - feel difference.

Comment: CALL_FUNCTION will be __always__ slower than STORE_FAST =)

Comment: It can be much, much slower than `INPLACE_ADD`, depending on the arguments.